# Angular 7: How to call a method without clicking?

Tags: angular, filter, angular-components, angular-template

I feel like I'm not seeing something obvious, however, I can't figure it out..
I have a layout component that displays a bunch of lists, each with its own title:

```
<h1>Vegetables</h1>
<food-list-component></food-list-component>

<h1>Fruit</h1>
<food-list-component></food-list-component>

<h1>Sweets</h1>
<food-list-component></food-list-component>
```

Inside the food-list-component I call a simple filtering method that accepts parameters (also `food type` for vegetables/fruit/sweets). Since everywhere else in the app I call this filter method based on some events (click or enter), I don't know how to filter these lists in this static layout component, which just displays lists.

Comment: Can you give an example of one call to the filter method? The parameters are not clear to me.

Comment: If you want to filter without event? When are you expecting the filter to occur? If for example you have an event `(click)="onFilter($event)"` .. You should be able to programitcally call that same event. `this.onFilter(event)`. However, it seems like this question could use more clarification.

Comment: Yes, I'm searching globally - filter method is inside a service (Observable that makes http calls) and uses rxjs Subject for the parameters.

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck The layout page is just for display, I'd like to have it filtered all the time. It's a beginner's question (to say the least).

Comment: @ConnorsFan something like (I don't have it at hand unfortunately): ```getFilteredFoodItems(vegetables, green, etc);```

Comment: The question should include a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Otherwise it is a guessing game for the people answering. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, all `food-list-component` instances are the same and has the same data. You need to filter each instance with a different filter (vegetables, fruits etc).

Define a filter property in your `food-list-component` as @Input. Then pass the required filter to each instance from your html.

```
export class FoodListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() filter: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Fetch items to be displayed in list
    // Filter the list using `filter`
  }

}
```

Then you can modify your html to pass the filter for each instance

```
<h1>Vegetables</h1>
<food-list-component filter="vegetables"></food-list-component>

<h1>Fruit</h1>
<food-list-component filter="fruits"></food-list-component>

<h1>Sweets</h1>
<food-list-component filter="sweets"></food-list-component>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly the answer I was looking for!